# How to display DISTINCT duplicates SQL

Tags: sql-server

So I have a table that displays when I put in my SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     r.CustomerId, o.ItemNumber, ItemIdentifier, o.ItemProductNumber
FROM 
    Owner o
INNER JOIN 
    Report r
ON 
    o.ReportId = r.ReportId
ORDER BY r.CustomerId
```

So the table that displays is

```
CustomerId  Item Number ItemIdentifier ItemProductNumber
NULL        NULL        NULL           NULL
NULL        2144        NULL           NULL
1           8797        NULL           NULL
2           6816        NULL           NULL
3           3436        NULL           NULL
4           4436        NULL           NULL
5           3523        NULL           NULL
6           6346        NULL           NULL
7           7452        NULL           NULL
7           7453        NULL           NULL
8           5475        NULL           NULL
9           6816        NULL           NULL
```

What I want to accomplish, and am having troubles with is getting the duplicate Item Number with different Customer Id.  In this case Customer 2 and 9.  I just want 2 and 9 to show. I see a lot of grouping and count and what not but that doesn't seem to be exactly what I am looking for.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one more approach.  I feel this is slightly cleaner, as it doesn't re-join your tables onto themselves, nor does it use `IN ()` which has been proven inefficient compared to `EXISTS ()`.

You can count occurrences of an `ItemNumber` using a window function.  In this case `COUNT`, and we include `OVER(PARTITION BY ItemNumber)` to specify the grouping.

Sample:

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (CusomerId INT, ItemNumber INT, ItemIdentifier INT, ItemProductNumber INT)
INSERT INTO @data
VALUES (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(NULL,2144,NULL,NULL),
(1,8797,NULL,NULL),
(2,6816,NULL,NULL),
(3,3436,NULL,NULL),
(4,4436,NULL,NULL),
(5,3523,NULL,NULL),
(6,6346,NULL,NULL),
(7,7452,NULL,NULL),
(7,7453,NULL,NULL),
(8,5475,NULL,NULL),
(9,6816,NULL,NULL)

;WITH Duplicates AS
(
    SELECT *, COUNT(2) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemNumber) AS CN
    FROM @data
)

SELECT * -- DISTINCT ItemNumber
FROM Duplicates
WHERE CN>1
```

To apply this to your scenario we would do:

```
;WITH X AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT r.CustomerId, o.ItemNumber, ItemIdentifier, o.ItemProductNumber
    FROM Owner o
    INNER JOIN Report r ON o.ReportId = r.ReportId
), Duplicates AS
(
    SELECT *, COUNT(2) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemNumber) AS CN
    FROM X
)

SELECT * -- DISTINCT ItemNumber
FROM Duplicates
WHERE CN>1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate this answer.  It also teaches me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do the trick

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (CustomerId int, ItemNumber int, ItemIdentifier int, ItemProductNumber int)
INSERT INTO @Table
values(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),(NULL,2144,NULL,NULL),(1,8797,NULL,NULL),
(2,6816,NULL,NULL),(3,3436,NULL,NULL),(4,4436,NULL,NULL),(5,3523,NULL,NULL),
(6,6346,NULL,NULL),(7,7452,NULL,NULL),(7,7453,NULL,NULL),(8,5475,NULL,NULL),
(9,6816,NULL,NULL)


SELECT *
FROM @Table
WHERE ItemNumber IN(SELECT ItemNumber
                    FROM @Table
                    GROUP BY ItemNumber
                    HAVING COUNT(ItemNumber) > 1)
```

If you still need to get the `DISTINCT` records, throw it into a CTE or subquery:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT DISTINCT r.CustomerId, o.ItemNumber, ItemIdentifier, 
o.ItemProductNumber
FROM [Owner] o
INNER JOIN Report r ON o.ReportId = r.ReportId
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE ItemNumber IN (SELECT ItemNumber
                     FROM CTE
                     GROUP BY ItemNumber
                     HAVING COUNT(ItemNumber) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer makes sense.

But I guess I have the time to try something different by modifying your original query to return the distinct `ItemNumber` and use that as a filter so that those that match are excluded from the list:

```
select * from (

-- this is your original query

SELECT DISTINCT
     r.CustomerId, o.ItemNumber, ItemIdentifier, o.ItemProductNumber
FROM 
    Owner o
INNER JOIN 
    Report r
ON 
    o.ReportId = r.ReportId)
AS T

-- and we are looking for item number not in the list

WHERE T.ItemNumber not in (

-- this is your original query
-- but modified to return records that are unique

SELECT DISTINCT
     o.ItemNumber
FROM 
    Owner o
INNER JOIN 
    Report r
ON 
    o.ReportId = r.ReportId
group BY o.ItemNumber
having count(o.itemnumber) = 1)
```

Think of it as `ALL RECORDS - UNIQUE RECORDS = DUPLICATE RECORDS`

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5396f/34

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
;WITH CTE1 AS (SELECT o.ItemNumber, CountItemNumbers = COUNT(1)
                FROM [Owner] o
                INNER JOIN Report r
                    ON o.ReportId = r.ReportId
                GROUP BY o.ItemNumber
                )

SELECT r.CustomerId, o.ItemNumber, ItemIdentifier, o.ItemProductNumber, C1.CountItemNumbers
FROM CTE1 C1
INNER JOIN [Owner] o
    ON C1.ItemNumber = o.ItemNumber
INNER JOIN Report r
    ON o.ReportId = r.ReportId
WHERE C1.CountItemNumbers > 1
```